# Find $a,b,c$ that minimize $F(a,b,c) = \int_{-1}^1 (t^2-a-bt-c\cos t)^2 dt$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

> Find $a,b,c$ that minimize $F(a,b,c) = \int_{-1}^1 (t^2-a-bt-c\cos
>  t)^2 dt$

I'm studying numerical methods and we're seeing least squares method and projection of things like polynomials and **orthogonality** and so. How should I minimize that thing in this context?

I think the first thing I should do it to see this as the orthogonal projection of something onto something like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/415897/166180). Can somebody help me?

Comment: Have you tried differentiating with respect to a, b, and c, and setting that equal to zero?

Comment: @Rebellos : partial integration works just fine for $\int t^k\cos t\,dt$.

Comment: You should notice that $F(a,b,c)$ is exactly the same as $SSQ$ for an infinite number of data points in linear regression. So, the simplest is to use the same approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the problem of minimising $F(a):=\int_S (\sum_i a_i f_i(t)-f(t))^2dt$ viz. $0=\frac{1}{2}\frac{\partial F}{\partial a_i}=\int_S(\sum_j a_j f_j-f)f_idt$. Writing $M_{ij}:=\int_S f_if_j dt,\,v_i:=\int_S ff_i dt$, we have the matrix equation $Ma=v$ i.e. $a=M^{-1}v$. In the case at hand we get $$\left(\begin{array}{c}
a\\
b\\
c
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\int_{-1}^{1}dt & \int_{-1}^{1}tdt & \int_{-1}^{1}\cos tdt\\
\int_{-1}^{1}tdt & \int_{-1}^{1}t^{2}dt & \int_{-1}^{1}t\cos tdt\\
\int_{-1}^{1}\cos tdt & \int_{-1}^{1}t\cos tdt & \int_{-1}^{1}\cos^{2}tdt
\end{array}\right)^{-1}\left(\begin{array}{c}
\int_{-1}^{1}t^{2}dt\\
\int_{-1}^{1}t^{3}dt\\
\int_{-1}^{1}t^{2}\cos tdt
\end{array}\right).$$I'll leave you to compute the integrals (which vanish if they have odd integrands), invert the matrix etc.

A geometric projection gives the same result. The general idea is to write $t^2=a+bt+c\cos t+g$ for some function "orthogonal" to each of $1,\,t,\,\cos t$ in the sense $$\int_{-1}^1 gdt=\int_{-1}^1 tgdt=\int_{-1}^1 g(t)\cos t dt=0.$$But even if you can identify such a $g$, the fact that $1,\,t,\,\cos t$ aren't orthogonal complicates further progress from taking inner products viz.$$\int_{-1}^1 t^2dt=a\int_{-1}^1 dt+b\int_{-1}^1 tdt+c\int_{-1}^1 \cos tdt$$etc. Oh, it *works*; it's just you get the above matrix inversion problem, complicated by its non-zero off-diagonal term $\int_{-1}^1\cos tdt$. Luckily, [we know](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invertible_matrix#Inversion_of_3_%C3%97_3_matrices) how to invert $3\times 3$ matrices.

Comment: You commented about geometric projection. The intent is to project $t^2$ onto the subspace generated by $a+bt+c\cos t$. In order to do the orthogonal projection I must have an inner product. How did you know to use $<f,g> = \int_{-1}^1 fg \ dt$?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs It's standard. By the way, use `\langle`,  `\rangle` for inner products.

Comment: what you mean by standard? I'm confused. There are lots of inner products that could be used. This is standard for everything?

Comment: @GuerlandoOCs On a vector space of functions over $S$, $\int_S f^\ast(t)w(t)g(t)dt$ is an inner product for suitable functions $w$ (I'll leave you to work out what is needed to ensure the product is positive-definite), but the choice $w=1$ is common. In the problem at hand, the choice of $w$ doesn't matter (as long as it's everywhere nonzero) because you could divide each $f_i$ by $w$; either way, you have to solve the above matrix inversion.